# Disable lowercase naming conversion in DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

Working with PostgreSQL, DataGrip converts all names of created tables/columns  to **lowercase**. How to disable it and keep original formatting? I prefer PascalCase.

It happens even if I run a SQL command manually in DataGrip console:

```
create table FooBar();
```

so the table `foobar` is created in db. I searched across the web and found nothing. I suppose it is not a PostgreSQL problem because pgAdmin3 doesn't change anything when it's doing the same things.

My environment:

- Windows 7 Pro
- DataGrip 2016.3.4
- PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Postgres feature, DataGrip has nothing to this issue.
If you want "PascalCaseIdentifiers" you have to use double quotes. 
Identifiers without quotes are case-insensitive. They are automatically converted to lower case.

Read about details [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

> pgAdmin3 doesn't change anything when it's doing the same things.

Quite the opposite, pgAdmin3 **adds** double quotes when e.g. an identifier contains capital letters (see the last tab `SQL` in `New table...` dialog).

In my (and not only my) honest opinion, using quoted identifiers is in general a very bad idea. It simply creates more problems then they are worth it.

Comment: It should be added that _using_ quoted identifiers is in general a very bad idea. It simply creates more problems then they are worth it.

Comment: Thanks! This different behaviour really embarassed me (newbie in PostgreSQL).

Comment: And this is why I don't like this functionality in pgAdmin3. It obscures real Postgres syntax.